# How can I close or dismiss from an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have put a ListView into a AlertDialog and I want to close the AlertDialog when I click on the ListView items; how can I do it?

```
public void createSearchDialog(final String[] Memo){
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View searchView = factory.inflate(R.layout.seach_dialog, null);

    lv = (ListView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_list);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, Memo, memo_PW));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     /// close dialog
        }
    });

    searchBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    searchBuilder.setTitle("Search")
           .setView(searchView)
           .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        })
           .show();     
}
```

Comment: check Listview.setOnItemClickListener() and dialog.dismiss()

Answer (score 1):

And from using the app context you can dismiss is by calling dimiss on it.

```
Application.getProgressDialog().dismiss();
```

This has to handled in the list view's `onItemClick()`

Comment: I can't find the dismiss function !

Comment: "Set the cancelability to true: `Dialog.setCancelable(false);`"  ...  
What?  You don't happen to mean `Dialog.setCancelable(true);`

Comment: Sorry, that is used when you want the dialog to be dismissed on clicking the back key.

Comment: You can call cancel on the dialog once you click on any of the list items . You have to call this on the dialog interface.

Comment: I can't find even the cancel() function

Answer (score 1):

just grab a pointer to your alertdialog like this

```
AlertDialog myDialog = searchBuilder.setTitle("Search")
           .setView(searchView)
           .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }).create();
```

then later on you can dismiss by calling

```
myDialog.dismiss()
```

Comment: but i don't want to add a button into my Search AlertDialog interface how can i do ?

Comment: @user1351316 you aren't adding a button, just adding a reference to the alertdialog called myDialog.  then pass this reference to your list.  In the list call the second line of code and should work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Mike i used an Activity with an AlertDialog theme :)